# Поиск результатов в БД MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Данный скрипт выводит все найденные результаты по маске из таблицы users. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку Город, сортировал по алфавиту?

```html
<div class="resultat"><table>
    <tbody><tr><th>Город:</th><th>Компания:</th><th>Телефон:</th><th>Категория:</th><th>Дата:</th></tr> </div>
    <?php
require 'scripts/connect.php';

$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do
{
 printf("<tr>
<td>" .$row['name'] . "</td>
<td>" .$row['last_name'] ."</td>
<td>" .$row['email'] . "</td>
<td>" .$row['facebook'] . "</td>
<td>" .$row['time'] . "</td>
</tr>");
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));


?></tbody></table>
```

Comment: для точного ответа на подобные вопросы нужна структура таблицы. и у Вас "город" только в шапке. кнопки у Вас нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположим, что Вы хотите сделать, чтобы при нажатии на ячейку шапки *город*, сортировка шла по столбцу *city* таблицы mysql. Тогда решение будет такое:

```
<div class="resultat"><table>
    <tbody><tr><th><a href="page.php?sort=city" title="сортировать по полю город">Город</a>:</th><th>Компания:</th><th>Телефон:</th><th>Категория:</th><th>Дата:</th></tr> </div>
    <?php
        require 'scripts/connect.php';
        $sqlAdd = (!empty($_GET["sort"]) && $_GET["sort"]=='city') ? " Order by city" : "";
        $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users".$sqlAdd;
        $result = mysql_query($sql_select);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        do
        {
            printf("<tr>
        <td>" .$row['name'] . "</td>
        <td>" .$row['last_name'] ."</td>
        <td>" .$row['email'] . "</td>
        <td>" .$row['facebook'] . "</td>
        <td>" .$row['time'] . "</td>
        </tr>");
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));

    ?>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: Заменил, была ошибка

Comment: Как думаете лучше, сделать все это при помощи https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html или как вы предложили?

Comment: все зависит только от Вас. Кто-то пользуется готовой библиотекой, кто-то делает по-своему. Библиотеки хороши тем, что сортировка идет на стороне клиента, но нужно смотреть, чтобы была кроссбраузерность и база данных не была большой.

Comment: Хорошо подскажите пожалуйста, как при нажатии на эту кнопку инвертировались результаты, и как добавить на остальные заголовки. Можно принцип.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сортировать на стороне сервера, также можно на стороне клиента.

Чтобы сортировать на стороне сервера необходимо на сервер передать признак критерия сортировки и исходя от того признака составить sql выражение. Например, при нажатии на кнопку Город запросом GET передается параметр sort=city. А скрипт измениться примерно так:

```
$orderBy = '';
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    switch ($_GET['sort']) {
         case 'city': $orderBy = ' order by `city`'; break;
         case '-city': $orderBy = ' order by `city` desc'; break;
    }
}
$sql = 'select * from `users`' . $orderBy;
```

Если сортировка производится на стороне клиента тогда можно использовать готовые скрипты типа https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html.

Как всегда у обеих методов есть плюсы и минусы. Например, если кол-во записей большое число, и данные загружаются постранично, тогда придется сортировать на стороне сервера.

Comment: Да я думаю проще всего сделать на стороне клиента. А если на стороне сервера, проще зайди в бд и там сделать сортировку?